# Expectation of proportion of matching pairs without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider an urn with only two types of coloured balls - say black and white.  We begin drawing pairs of balls and continue until the urn is empty.  What is the distribution for the count of matching ball colours - ie draw 2 white or 2 black (success).  What is the expectation - E ( proportion of balls matching).

I think this is something close to the hyper geometric distribution but I can't fit it into the the standard parameters.  I also realise that for a small sample for a large urn of balls, it could be approximated by binomial but in my case I don't want the approximation.

Comment: You need to specify the ratio of black to white initially.  For example if they are equal to start with you will get about half matching.  If most are one color, you will get a much higher proportion of matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can calculate the expectation as follows. Assume that the urn initially contains $m$ black balls and $n$ white balls. Enumerate the balls by numbers from $1$ to $m+n$. There are $(m+n)!$ different possible sequences of drawn balls. By symmetry of the draw probabilities, each of these sequences has probability $1/(m+n)!$ to be realized. Now for any $1\le k<m+n$ define a random variable $A_k=1$, if colors of $k$-th and $k+1$-th drawn balls match, and $A_k=0$, otherwise. It is easy to see that the probability $$P(A_k=1)=\frac{(m(m-1)+n(n-1))(m+n-2)!}{(m+n)!}.$$ Then

$$E(\mbox{proportion of color matching})=\frac{E(\mbox{number of color mathching})} 
{\mbox{number of pair of balls}}=$$ $$\frac{1}{m+n-1}E\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m+n-1} A_k\right)=
\frac{1}{m+n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{m+n-1} E(A_k)=$$ $$\frac{1}{m+n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{m+n-1} 
\frac{m(m-1)+n(n-1)}{(m+n)(m+n-1)}=\frac{m(m-1)+n(n-1)}{(m+n)(m+n-1)}.$$